# How to set up styleClass inside ts file?

Tags: css, angular, primeng, new-style-class

I want to create css element inside ts file and pass it as a styleClass to PrimeNg Toast.

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.innerHTML = '::ng-deep .cssClass { background-color: #e62323; border: solid #8A427A; border-width: 0 0 0 6px; color: #2c1e30; }';
this.messageService.add({severity:'custom', summary:'Service Message', detail:'Via MessageService', styleClass: 'cssClass', sticky: true});
```

The above code is not working for me, style is not applied.
Could someone help me with that?

EDIT: I tried to catch the p-toast and append style but it's not applied still.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  let message = document.getElementsByClassName('p-toast-message-custom')[0];
  message.appendChild(style);
}, 100)
```

Comment: append style element in DOM

Comment: I don't know how, because it's a p-toast so it's not available from the beginning, only when it appears

Answer (score 1):

In Angular we should not set a style with directly DOM manipulation. The reason is:

1. Angular cannot detect changes if you do this by hand
2. Angular render components and create and update the DOM.

So its possible, but not a good way. In your case, set **append** the element to the DOM. Then it will works, I think.

#### The Angular Way

Each component has it one contained CSS/SCSS.

What you can do is to use Angulars board means, like `ngStyle`, `ngClass` and so on. example:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-color':'green'}"></<div>
```

You can do it with property binding, too:

```
// Code
getColor(country) { (2)
    switch (country) {
      case 'UK':
        return 'green';
      case 'USA':
        return 'blue';
      case 'HK':
        return 'red';
    }
  }

// Html
<div [ngStyle]="{'color':getColor(person.country)}">Test</div>
```

`ngClass` does the same but let you set a class flexible to any component.

```
// Code
val: number = 9;

// Html
<td [ngClass]="val > 10 ? 'red' : 'green'">{{ val }}</td>
```

[Link](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) to `ngClass` docu, [link](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) to `ngStyle` docu.

Comment: ngStyle will not work in my case I think, because it refers to general p-toast component. This is not overwritting the style: <p-toast [ngStyle]="{'background-color': '#e62323'}"></p-toast>

Answer (score 0):

To add a class to a message using PrimeNG's MessageService, you can use the add method and provide an optional options object that includes a styleClass property.

Here's an example code snippet that demonstrates how to add a class to a message:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  template: `
    <button (click)="showSuccess()">Show Success Message</button>
  `,
  providers: [MessageService]
})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {}

  showSuccess() {
    this.messageService.add({severity:'success', summary:'Success', detail:'Message Content', 
      options: {styleClass: 'my-custom-class'}});
  }
}
```

```css
.my-custom-class {
  background-color: #b3ffb3;
  color: #006600;
  border: 1px solid #006600;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I have the color values inside ts class, because they need to be set dynamically

Comment: That class should be added to the p-messages component, not within the service: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/messages/messages.ts